# CLion does not pick up (complex) pre-processor definitions

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

**EDIT**: Turns out the problem was the complexity of my project. Using the simple example below works as expected, but CLion cannot make sense of the complex dependencies of the project I'm working on. Using the linked question as a workaround for now.

I'm using CLion as my C++ IDE and I've added a simple pre-processor directive as a CMake option:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(cmake_macro_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

option(SIMPLE_FLAG "My simple flag." ON)
if(SIMPLE_FLAG)
    add_definitions(-DSIMPLE_FLAG) # Using CMake 3.10
endif()

add_executable(cmake_macro_test main.cpp)
```

Then my code has conditional compilation sections of the form:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

#ifdef SIMPLE_FLAG
// Do things
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
#else
  // Do other things
  std::cout << "Goodbye, World!" << std::endl;
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

The flag is set to on by default, so I expected Clion would pick it up from the CMakeLists.txt and highlight the relevant parts of the code.

However, Clion views the `//Do things` part of the code as dead, and does provide syntax highlighting or auto-complete for that section, unless I actually re-define the flag in the same file which would defeat the purpose of the CMake option.

Is this a known issue with CLion? Is there some way to guarantee that pre-processor flags get picked up by the IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining preprocessor symbols for CLion analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378169/defining-preprocessor-symbols-for-clion-analyzer)

Comment: Is the problem only for IDE highlighting? That is, if you build the project, is the macro definition picked correctly?

Comment: Is the missing `)` also in your actual CMake file?

Comment: Botje no, this was an example, I'll fix it now. @Tsyvarev I don' think it's getting picked up from the build either, because I'm not seeing the expected output when running. Do I need to set such flags explicitly, even if they default to ON? I usually use CMake to build outside of CLion (remote dev) so I don't run applications through Clion, just want to have code prediction in the relevant regions.

Comment: So, the build process works incorrectly too (that is, it works in a manner which you don't expect). BTW, have you tried to add this definition in `CMakeLists.txt` **unconditionally**? Please, provide more detailed [mcve]: exact `CMakeLists.txt` which adds definition and builds the application, the C code which uses this definition and the exact error message (which includes the name of file being compiled).

Comment: I just created a small sample project to try this out and everything works perfectly fine for me. So it's not a general problem with CLion. I don't know if this is your problem but note that options in CMake are cached and once a value is set in the cache changing it in the CMakeLists.txt is not enough. You have to either change the value in the cmake cache or reset the CMake cache (Tools->CMake->Reset Cache and Reload Project).

Comment: Yes @GSIO01 I created an MRE as Tsyvarev recommended and it works fine. The project I'm working on is too complex I'm afraid, so I'm using the linked workaround instead.